# Fail install JavaServer Faces 2.0

Tags: java, maven

How can I fix this error ?

```
Failed while installing JavaServer Faces 2.0.
'web' : unable to configure web module for JavaServer Faces
```

here is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>web</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>**/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

here is my faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

</faces-config>
```

and here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

With JSF 2.2, new namespaces were introduced - **xmlns.jcp.org** replaces **java.sun.com**, see http://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/jsf22-namespaces/

```
<facelet-taglib version="2.2"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd">
</facelet-taglib>
```

Comment: when I add facelet-taglib, the error like this: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'facelet-taglib' is not complete. One of '{"http://
 xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":description, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":display-name, "http://
 xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":icon, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":library-class, "http://
 xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":namespace}' is expected.

Comment: can you post your complete pom?